# Selenium webdriver error

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

My program is :

public class demo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    //runtest("test","test");


try{

    //Open excel file
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("D:\\test.xls");

    //Access excel sheet
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    HSSFSheet sheet= wb.getSheet("test");

    //Get date row by row
     for(int count = 1;count<=sheet.getLastRowNum();count++)

    {

    HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(count);
    System.out.println("Test rows are" + row.getCell(0).toString());
    runtest(row.getCell(1).toString(),row.getCell(2).toString());

    }

    fs.close();



    }

catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Test data file not found");
}


}

public static void runtest(String strsearch, String strtitle) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    element.submit();

    if(driver.getTitle().equals(strtitle)){


    System.out.println("Page title is" + strtitle + "true");
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Page title should be" + strtitle +"But page title is" + driver.getTitle());


}
    driver.quit();
}}
```

Getting error below :

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at demo.main(demo.java:40)

I think it is not going inside method. Please help.

Comment: You have a NullPointer exception at line 40. Look at the code at line 40 figure out which object is null. Then figure out why it is null and fix..

Comment: That element looks ok. I have already tried using id also. Getting same error.

If I put code below at top then it runs only for 1st value:

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

Basically I am trying to fetch value from excel , search to google and match title.

Comment: Have you created project using maven? And show your import statements also

Comment: Nope. Project created using selenium Jar , POI excel jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mustn't have the named the sheet to "test" in the "test.xls" file.

Hence, NullPointerException is thrown, as the sheet with name "test" is not found.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. my sheet name was sheet1.